# Iterative dfs algorithm gives sigkill error

Tags: c, iteration, depth-first-search

Pseudo code for iterative dfs algorithm

```
Mark all unblocked positions in the maze as "UNVISITED"
   push the start position's coordinates on the stack
   mark the start position as “VISITED”
  While (stack is not empty and end has not been found)
    if the coordinate at the Top of the Stack is the end position
      then end has been found (break out of loop)
    if the coordinate at the Top of the Stack has an unvisited (and unblocked)       
neighbor
      push the coordinates of one unvisited neighbor on the stack
      mark that one unvisited neighbor as visited
    else
      pop the coordinate at the Top of the Stack
  If the stack is empty
      The maze has no solution
  else
      The items on the stack contain the coordinates of the solution from the end 
of the maze to the start of the maze.
```

C code for iterative dfs algorithm that returns the maze by value and stack by reference

```
maze DEPTH_FIRST_SEARCH(Stack *s, maze m1)
{
    int found = 0;
    //Mark all unblocked positions in the maze as "UNVISITED
    //push the start position's coordinates on the stack 
    int visited[m1.xsize+2][m1.ysize+2];
    for(int i = 0; i < m1.xsize+2;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1.ysize+2; j++){
            visited[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Start: x: %d y:%d", m1.xstart,m1.ystart );
    push(&s, m1.xstart,m1.ystart);
    //mark the start position as “VISITED”
    visited[m1.xstart][m1.ystart] = 1;
    //While (stack is not empty and end has not been found)
    while(found != 1)
    {
        struct Node* node = top(&s);
        printf("x: %d y:%d", node->xcoord,node->ycoord );
        //if the coordinate at the Top of the Stack is the end position
        if((node->xcoord == m1.xend) && (node->ycoord == m1.yend))
        {
            //then end has been found (break out of loop)
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
        //if the coordinate at the Top of the Stack has an unvisited (and unblocked) down neighbor
        else if(visited[(node->xcoord)-1][node->ycoord] = 0 && m1.arr[(node->xcoord)-1][node->ycoord] == '.')
        {
            //push the coordinates of one unvisited neighbor on the stack
            //mark that one unvisited neighbor as visited  
             printf("down" );
            push(&s,(((node->xcoord)-1)), node->ycoord );
           visited[(node->xcoord)-1][node->ycoord] = 1;
        }
        //if the coordinate at the Top of the Stack has an unvisited (and unblocked) up neighbor
        else if(visited[(node->xcoord)+1][node->ycoord] = 0 && m1.arr[(node->xcoord)+1][node->ycoord] == '.' )
        {
            //push the coordinates of one unvisited neighbor on the stack
            //mark that one unvisited neighbor as visited 
             printf("up" );
            push(&s,((node->xcoord)+1), node->ycoord);
            visited[(node->xcoord)+1][node->ycoord] = 1;
        }
        //if the coordinate at the Top of the Stack has an unvisited (and unblocked) right neighbor
         else if(visited[(node->xcoord)][node->ycoord+1] = 0 && m1.arr[(node->xcoord)][node->ycoord+1] == '.')
        {
            //push the coordinates of one unvisited neighbor on the stack
            //mark that one unvisited neighbor as visited  
            printf("Right" );
            push(&s,node->xcoord, ((node->ycoord)+1 ));
            visited[(node->xcoord)][node->ycoord+1] = 1;
        }
        //if the coordinate at the Top of the Stack has an unvisited (and unblocked) left neighbor
        else if(visited[(node->xcoord)][node->ycoord-1] = 0 && m1.arr[(node->xcoord)-1][node->ycoord-1] == '.')
        {
            //push the coordinates of one unvisited neighbor on the stack
            //mark that one unvisited neighbor as visited 
            printf("left" );
            push(&s,node->xcoord, ((node->ycoord)-1) );
            visited[(node->xcoord)][node->ycoord-1] = 1;
        }
        else if(is_empty(s)==1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            pop(&s);
        }

    }
    return m1;
}
```

inside main

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  maze m1;
  Stack *s;
  //commandline arg checker
  //debug checker
  //take in file mazedata
  //print out maze m1
  m1 = DEPTH_FIRST_SEARCH(&s, m1);
  //print out maze m1 after the dfs
}
```

Input 
    ./a.out mazedata1.txt
Output

```
size: 10, 20
start: 1, 1
end: 10, 20
**********************
*s........*..........*
*........*...........*
*..*....*............*
*.*....*.............*
**....*..............*
*....*...............*
*...*................*
*..*.................*
*....................*
*...................e*
**********************
```

I searched iterative dfs algorithms for solving mazes online but i couldn't find anything on it only recursive dfs algorithms for solving graphs and trees. My output only prints out the maze before the dfs function and then it stops working in the dfs function and doesn't print the maze after the function. I don't know if I need to include the stack functions and node structs. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Use a debugger, and a *lot* smaller maze. Start with one that has two positions, start and end.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you passing a Stack (that the main function doesn't need) by reference, but pass and return a maze by value?

Comment: I pass the stack by reference because I will print the stack in reverse order to print the path from start to end

Comment: I used a 4x4 maze and put start in position 1, 1 and end in 2, 1 but it still crashes the program.

Comment: btw you have `Stack *s` and pass `&s`, but the function accepts `Stack*`. This shouldn't compile.

Comment: Debugger. What does it tell you?

Comment: i ran the debugger and it kept on printing x:1 y: 1 until it crashed

Comment: You need to learn how to use the debugger. It involves tracing your program line by line and examining its state after each step.

Comment: I was using online debugger but when i put it in gdb it keeps on running until it says killed

Comment: I think it was in a infinite loop because visited[(node->xcoord)-1][node->ycoord] = 0 didn't check only assigned 0 to visited